# factor of safety

Tags: statistical-significance, feature-selection, experiment-design, validation

I need to validate a specification on a part. 
The requirement is to withstand a minimum 1 kg of force (i.e. not fail at less than 1 kg).
I was told that if I measure, on 6 specimens, a force of 2.5 kgs (i.e. factor of safety of 2.5), and all the specimens pass, I can say that with a 95% confidence and 95% reliability that the part meets the specification of >1 kg failure force. 
Is this true? What is the rationale/math to support this statement?

Comment: Nothing in your problem statement justifies it as far as I can see. No doubt there's some additional information or assumptions being used there. Do you know what definition of reliability is being used?